# Passing windows credentials through web application, to WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, impersonation

I've checked other questions, but I can't find a working answer

I have a .Net web application which successfully takes on the callers windows credentials (Thread.CurrentPrincipal is my windows user).

Within that app, I call to a WCF service, but my windows identity isn't passed up.  Regardless of what I put in the binding:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```